# when adding logo into the report the crystal report add gray background color into the logo

Tags: crystal-reports

When adding logo in my reports the logo background color is transparent but 
the crystal replaced with gray color .
My logo extensions .png 
I tried too many way but it doesn't work like add image into word document

Answer (score 0):

Crystal converts images to bitmap.

Try to save that png as jpeg and then try to add.

Comment: You can check for more possible solutions: [here](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3503680)